Optimal strategy for 4-in-a-row on 5-by-5 board with random setup and a transfer
Is the optimal strategy known for the following variant of 4-in-a-row where the first 2 moves are random and the 2nd player can once move a mark to any location.

Win condition: 4-in-a-row.

Board: 5x5.

Setup:

Player1 randomly place a mark on the board.
Player2 randomly place a mark on the board, which can not be in the center.


Play:

After the first move by player 1, player 2 can move their piece.
Next, the turns alternating like in a regular tic-tac-toe.



Two questions:

Is this game solved/solvable?
Does player 2 have a strategy that can guarantee a win for every random first move? If so, what is that strategy?


Since you can force 3x3 to a draw, 4 for a winning condition should be even easier to force to a draw, random or not

@Zibelas, you are wrong, it is easier to make a k-in-a-row because the board is bigger.  For example, a 3-in-a-row on a 5-by-5 board is very easy win by the first player.

@Zibelas, what I mean is that there are several forces that push in different directions: the 4-in-a-row instead of 3-in-a-row push the game to a draw but the bigger board push the game to a first player win.  The random moves setup pushes the game to some games won by each of the players.

This game is Solvable due to Zermelo's theorem.  I don't know if someone solved it.  This game is actually a mix of 25 * 24 games (setups). Solving the game means to solve each setup (which is a game with no affect of chance) and find if it is a p1 win, p1 lose or a draw.
The notation of a m,n,k-game talks about m-by-n board and win by making k-in-a-row.  If we put a side the random setup and the transfer, a (5,5,4) is a draw. However increasing the board by a single row to (6,5,4) makes it a first player win.
This variant is a (5,5,4) with random setup and a transfer action of p2. Because the vanilla (5,5,4) is very close to p1 win, I think most setups are either p1 win or p2 win (but not a draw).
